Weight paint blur and smear can only draw at full strength. How do I fix it?
I am trying to weight paint my model but when I go to blur and smear the brush just continues to add weight like it is drawing with full strength/turning everything red. Turning down the strength doesn't work. It was working before but after I went to check my rig it no longer works. How can I fix it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When I use the blur tool it would gradually spread out the weight around the vertex and the smear tool would push the different weights to other vertices. Now when I use the tool it would just paint the vertices red like I was drawing with full strength on if that makes sense.

hello could you please share your object, at least a small part, so that we can try?
